# Checking multiple variables in if condition

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
float math , physics ,literature , chemistry ;

cout << "Enter math score : ";
cin >> math ;
cout << "Enter physics score : ";
cin >> physics ;
cout << "Enter chemistry score : ";
cin >> chemistry ;
cout << "Enter literature score : ";
cin >> literature ;
```

I want to check my variables, but it doesn't work.

```
//Check inputs
if ( math , physics , chemistry , literature > 20 ){
    cout << "Error ... The score should be in range (0,20).";
```

Comment: My suggestion is that you make a generic function to get input, with a prompt and a limit as arguments. Then the function could iterate until the input is in the range requested and return the value then. Then call that function once for each input.

Comment: "it didn't worked" is not a problem description. What error did you get? You should explain the specific problem when writing a question. Anyway, this particular question is just a result of not having read enough about the language before writing code, sorry.

Comment: On another note, you forget to check against the lower bound (`0`). And is the input supposed to be a floating-point number or an integer? Is e.g. `12.34` a valid input?

Comment: It would be nice if we could do `if (std::ranges::any_of({ math, physics, chemistry, literature }, [](auto score){ return > 20; })` ...

Comment: ... and on other notes: always check input after reading if it was successful!

Answer (score 6):

```
if ( math , physics , chemistry , literature > 20 ){
```

While this is valid C++, it's almost definitely not doing what you want (see [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) for more). Ordinarily you'd do what you're looking for like:

```
if ( math > 20 || physics > 20 || chemistry > 20 || literature > 20 ){
```

You *can* however, shorten this with a call to `std::max`:

```
if (std::max({math, physics, chemistry, literature}) > 20) {
```

This'll work since you only really care about the greatest value here. If the greatest value of the four is less than 20, then it means ALL are less than 20.

Comment: I have never seen std::max being called that way, thanks a lot!

Comment: @a.Li That's the overload that takes an `std::initializer_list`, and yes quite handy. Ditto `std::min()` of course.

Comment: @a.Li: It's a C++11 onwards thing. A lot of software stacks out there are C++03 and less.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is allowed by the language:

`if (math, physics, chemistry, literature > 20 ) {`

It's a standard usage of [the comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do), but it does not give you the expected result.

You should rewrite it like this instead:

`if (math > 20 || physics > 20 || chemistry > 20 || literature > 20) {`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of write `if ( math , physics , chemistry , literature > 20 )` you should write:

`if ( math > 20 || physics > 20 || chemistry > 20 || literature > 20 )`
if you want to check if even just one element is bigger than 20;
`if ( math > 20 && physics > 20 && chemistry > 20 && literature > 20 )`
if you want to check if all the elements are bigger than 20.